# Injury-free proof of Cof being $\Sigma^0_3$-complete

Tags: logic, computability

How can I prove, without using priority argument, that Cof, the set of indices of cofinite c.e. sets, is $\Sigma^0_3$-complete?

I know an injury-free proof of Rec being $\Sigma^0_3$-complete, where Cof is the set of indices of recursive c.e. sets.  I tried to reduce Rec to Cof to obtain an injury-free proof for Cof, but it seems nontrivial.

EDIT: in the first version I wrote Rec where I should have written Cof, and vice versa.  Sorry about my confusion.

Comment: What is the injury-free proof that Rec is $\Sigma^0_3$-complete?